# Pipeline with RF, PCA and CV generating error

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, random-forest, cross-validation, grid-search

I am fitting a random forest regressor model, with pipelined PCA and gridsearch for hyperparameter selection, but it somehow gives me an error. Below is my code:

```py
params_rf = {'RandomForestRegressor__n_estimators': [300, 400, 500],
             'RandomForestRegressor__max_depth': [4, 6, 8],
             'RandomForestRegressor__min_samples_leaf': [0.1, 0.2],
             'RandomForestRegressor__max_features': ['log2', 'sqrt']}

pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                 ('reducer', PCA(n_components=50)),
                  ('regressor',RandomForestRegressor(verbose = 3))])

rf_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe,
                     param_grid = params_rf,
                     cv =3,
                     verbose=3)

rf_cv.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Error message:

```py
Invalid parameter RandomForestRegressor_max_depth for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('reducer', PCA(n_components=50)),
                ('regressor', RandomForestRegressor(verbose=3))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

I have tried remove the 'RandomForestRegressor_' prefix, the problem still persists. And I'm pretty such `max_depth` is in fact a hyperparameter in `RandomForestRegressor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RandomForestRegressor`, as used in your pipeline, has already a name, `regressor`; you should refer to it by this name, instead of `RandomForestRegressor`. Change your `params_rf` to:

```py
params_rf = {'regressor__n_estimators': [300, 400, 500],
             'regressor__max_depth': [4, 6, 8],
             'regressor__min_samples_leaf': [0.1, 0.2],
             'regressor__max_features': ['log2', 'sqrt']}
```